# Official road and rail networks of Brazil

Tags: data, road, brazil, railroad

I am looking for the official road and rail networks of Brazil, produced by a government department. I haven't been able to find it on the [IGBE website](https://www.ibge.gov.br) and the [Humanitarian Data Exchange utilises a clip from OpenStreetMap](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/wfp-geonode-brazil-road-network-main-roads).

I would need this in shapefile format ideally and technically only for the legal Amazon.

Comment: Open data requests are better researched in [opendata.se].  GIS SE is for *problem-solving*, while working with the data, not for list compilation questions for which no one correct answer exists.

Answer (score 3):

The world bank has a dataset at http://datacatalog.worldbank.org/search/dataset/0038245 . The dataset metadata claim it is "based on the current network, government plans, and maps from rail transport agencies. " and licensed CC-BY 4.0